# Exchange 2010 delays messages

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, windows-sbs-2011

I've got a problem with an Exchange 2010 server runnnig on Windows SBS 2011.
Some emails are stuck in the queue and they get one of these errors:

> 451 Timeout waiting for client input
>
> 421 4.4.2 Connection dropped due to SocketError

Here is a mail that got this error:

> Identity: FS01\4096\33983
>
> Subject: [subject here]
>
> Internet Message ID: [id here]
>
> From Address: [adress here]
>
> Status: Ready
>
> Size (KB): 335
>
> Message Source Name: FromLocal
>
> Source IP: 255.255.255.255
>
> SCL: -1
>
> Date Received: 20-7-2015 12:37:32
>
> Expiration Time: 22-7-2015 12:37:32
>
> Last Error: 421 4.4.2 Connection dropped due to SocketError
>
> Queue ID: FS01\4096
>
> Recipients:  [recipient]

I've checked if the firewall on the server was blocking it, but that's not the case.

One solution that I found was pinging and then decreasing the size like this:

> ping [ip] -l 1472 -f = TIME OUT
>
> ping [ip] -l 1465 -f = TIME OUT
>
> ping [ip] -l 1464 -f = GOOD

Then setting the MTU, I've done that and set it to 1500 but that changed nothing.

I've also tried sending emails with telnet from that server, that worked, those messages didn't go in the queue.

We have other exchange servers that are configured exactly the same but only this one has this problem.

I'm running out of ideas, does anyone have a suggestion of what it might be?

**EDIT:** I'm still stuck on this, that's why I'm bumping this question.